# Swift sort an array of enums by their enum declared order

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, enums

How can I sort my array of enums to be sorted by the declared order?

```
enum EducationOptions: String {
    case gcse = "GCSE"
    case aLevel = "A Level"
    case bachelors = "Bachelors"
    case masters = "Masters"
    case doctorate = "Doctorate"
    case other = "Other"
}

var arrayOfEducationOptions: [EducationOptions] = [.masters, .gcse, .aLevel]
```

I want to sort arrayOfEducationOptions to get [.gcse, .aLevel, .masters] as per the order declared in the enum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort objects by its enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864278/how-to-sort-objects-by-its-enum-value)

Comment: Thanks.  Question on that - the example shown references a Class.  I'm using an array, so how can I convert `data.sort { $0.workout.difficulty! < $1.workout.difficulty! }` to work with my array?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a comparable protocol to the enum?

```
enum EducationOptions: String {
   case gcse = "GCSE"
   case aLevel = "A Level"
   case bachelors = "Bachelors"
   case masters = "Masters"
   case doctorate = "Doctorate"
   case other = "Other"

   var order: Int {
      switch self {
      case .gcse: return 1
      case .aLevel: return 2
      case .bachelors: return 3
      case .masters: return 4
      case .doctorate: return 5
      case .other: return 6
   }
}

extention EquctionOptions: Comparable { 


   static func < (lhs: EducationOptions, rhs: EducationOptions) -> Bool {
      lhs.order < rhs.order
   }
}
```

then you can just sort the array.

```
let array = [.masters, .gcse, .aLevel]
let sorted = array.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
```

there may be a better way to set the order values in the array while having the String raw value as well, but not of the top of my head

Comment: Thanks.  Using `array.sorted()` on the last line also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make it conform to `CaseIterable` protocol and use the static `allCases` property:

```swift
enum EducationOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case gcse = "GCSE"
    case aLevel = "A Level"
    case bachelors = "Bachelors"
    case masters = "Masters"
    case doctorate = "Doctorate"
    case other = "Other"
}

let arrayOfEducationOptions = EducationOptions.allCases
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Vadim has the right idea, but if you want to sort an arbitrary list of EducationOptions, you could use code like this:

```
enum EducationOptions: String, CaseIterable {
    case gcse = "GCSE"
    case aLevel = "A Level"
    case bachelors = "Bachelors"
    case masters = "Masters"
    case doctorate = "Doctorate"
    case other = "Other"
}

let allCases = EducationOptions.allCases

var arrayOfEducationOptions: [EducationOptions] = [.masters, .gcse, .aLevel]
    .sorted {allCases.firstIndex(of: $0)! <  allCases.firstIndex(of: $1)! }

arrayOfEducationOptions.forEach { print($0) }
```

Note that that code is a naive implementation, and would scale very poorly as the number of cases grows. (It would have at least `O(n²)` time performance, and probably even worse (`O(n²•log n)`). For larger enums you'd want to rewrite it to create an array of structs that included indexes from the sample array of enums, and then sort **that**.